# how can i chrome popup confirmation in python selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, alert

i use python and i want click "ok" button in Chrome selenium.

[image: Chrome Popup]

how can i click "ok" in selenium?

Comment: We need to see your code and a link to that page in order to help here. At least to see the HTML of that dialog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accepting alert with Selenium in Python can be done with this:

```py
driver.switch_to.alert.accept()
```

Answer (score 1):

Updated answer with testing on PC

```
from time import sleep

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://testautomationpractice.blogspot.com/")

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='HTML9']/div[1]/button").click()
sleep(5)
driver.switch_to.alert.dismiss() #  or .accept()
```

Comment: `AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'switchTo'`

Comment: @soundwave Ronin wrote Java code while the topic starter uses Python. It's "only" syntax issue. See my answer with Python style command.

Comment: No, it is a python code, I was on the go. Now I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The .alert.accept() some others are mentioning should work, but from my experience it didnt work on the applications I ran.

These two ways worked for me:

1. since its a pop up and the focus is on the button you need you can simply use OS.system or subprocess library command 'enter' on the keyboard.
2. this is a more tedious way. If you are on linux and are fine with adding mouse clicks, use the library xdotool find the coordinates on the selenium window use it to mouse click in that spot after a few seconds lag

links:
subprocess:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html
xdotool:
https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/xdotool.1.html